# Como usar curvas bezier para descrever animação 3d em c++ de forma eficiente?

Tags: c++, animação, otimização, vector, 3d

Estou desenvolvendo um programa 3d em c/c++, já fiz a parte de renderização dos objetos, está faltando a parte de animação, basicamente desejo usar uma lista de valores (frames) cada um contendo o tempo do frame, a posição (valor) do frame e 2 controles para usar na interpolação de curvas bezier, pois desejo criar animações bastante longas que não posso usar uma lista de valores frame por frame, portanto vou usar uma lista bem espaçada e utilizar a interpolação bezier para obter um valor interpolado suave entre 2 frames.

```
// possibilidade de estrutura para armazenar a informação 
// dos frames em um array ou vetor que posteriormente será interpolado.
struct frame{ 
 float time; // tempo do frame em que 1 unidade = 16.67ms
 float point; // valor do frame
 float c1 // control point 1, usado na interpolação com o frame anterior
 float c2 // control point 2, usado na interpolação com o próximo frame
};
// C1 e C2 são os pontos de controle usados na interpolação 
// com a função de curvas bezier para dar uma suavidade na 
// animação (mas possivelmente vou modificar o que cada um significa)
// obs: No caso do primeiro frame o ponto de controle C1 
// apesar de existente não é usado, no caso do ultimo frame 
// da animação o ponto de controle C2 não é utilizado.

// exemplo de uso das estruturas frame, provavelmente será 
// um vetor com centenas de frames (talvez milhares dependendo da animação)
std::vector<frame> frames; 

// declaração da função bezier ainda não implementada, mas 
// sua implementação é simples para mim e está fora do 
// escopo da pergunta, pois apenas faz a interpolação entre 2 pontos
float bezier(frame& p1, frame& p2, float t);

// Exemplo de procura funcional, mas deixa a desejar em 
// processamento necessário para encontrar o frame a ser 
// usado devido a probabilidade de ter que atravessar uma 
// gigantesca lista de frames comparando milhares de valores 
// até ser encontrado o valor procurado.  
float getFramePos(float time){ // primeira versão
    for (int i = 0; i < frames.size(); i++){
        if (frames[i].time => time)
            return bezier(frames[i-1], frames[i], time);     
    };
 };
// Bezier é uma função que pega como argumentos 2 frames 
// e o tempo e faz os devidos cálculos e retorna o valor da 
// interpolação bezier, mas sua implementação está fora 
// do escopo da questão.

float position = getFramePos(236.57f);
// tempo provavelmente será 1.0f = 1 segundo/60 fps, pois 1 é 
// igual a 1 frame em taxas de atualização de 60 quadros por 
// segundo, utilizo float por também poder rodar a mais de 60 
// FPS, então se caso for 120 fps pode-se usar 0.5 para cada 
// quadro e 0.25 para cada quadro a 240 fps. Ajuda a ter boa 
// interpolação de animação e taxa de quadros variáveis,
// é possível que seja substituído por double para maior
// precisão em animações longas
```

Em uma lista pequena essa função **getFramePos()** é rápida, pois são poucas comparações, mas em uma grande lista de milhares de frames, com muitos objetos que cada um possui sua própria animação e possivelmente tenham mais de uma animação sendo executada ao mesmo tempo, a função se torna um desastre na procura principalmente quando o tempo procurado na animação esteja no final da lista de frames, pois acaba-se percorrendo toda a lista e comparando todos os tempos.

A minha questão é: Qual a forma mais rápida de se obter o valor desejado da lista de frames procurando por um determinado tempo?

Obs: Os valores time da lista de frames estarão sempre em ordem crescente.

Segunda versão em rumo a otimização:

```
// implementação via classe
struct frame{ 
 float time;
 float point; // atualmente float para simplicidade e melhor 
//depuração, mais tarde também adicionarei float2, float3 
//(mais usado) e matrix3x3 ou matrix4x4 (otimização para 
//evitar de se ficar criando matix de transformação a cada frame)
 float c1;
 float c2;
};

class animation {
    std::vector<frame> frames;
    float lastTime; // ajuda para procura
    int lastFrame; // ajuda para procura
// em animação linear ajuda muito a não precisar ficar 
// procurando em toda a lista de frames, pois é quase certo que 
// o próximo tempo pode ser o mesmo frame ou o próximo 
// frame, isso só em animação linear, mas se caso for pegar 
// um tempo aleatório é praticamente inútil.

    animation(vector &v): lastTime(0), lastFrame(0){};

    ~animation(){
        frames.clear();
     };
    // função melhorada para animação linear/sequencial
    float get(float time){
        int i = 0;
        if (time >= lastTime && time <= frames[frames.size()-1].time)
            i = lastFrame;
        for (; i < frames.size(); i++){
            if (frames[i].time >= time && frames[i-1].time <= time){
                lastFrame = i-1;
                lastTime = time;
                return bezier(frames[i-1], frames[i], time); 
            };   
        };
    };
};
```

Uma futura modificação será mover **lastTime** e **lastFrame** para fora da classe, para o código que chamar por **get()** e passar os valores **lastTime** e **lastFrame** como argumento, pois mais de um objeto poderá estar usando a mesma animação acessando tempos diferentes.
Ainda não implementei, mas acredito que a busca binária pode trazer grande economia de comparações (em acessos aleatórios não sequenciais), proporcionando ganhos em performance e menor uso de CPU, que é o meu objetivo.

Mas minha questão ainda é: A utilização do último resultado de tempo e frame para execução linear e a busca binária para casos de acesso aleatório é a melhor otimização possível de se utilizar? Ou existe alguma alternativa mais eficiente ou mais algum teste que possa diminuir ainda mais a quantidade de comparações de tempos?

Answer (score 0):

Analisando a eficiência da busca binária, contando o número de comparações percebi que realmente é a melhor otimização, podendo até descartar a otimização de busca sequencial, pois eu acabei subestimando o "poder" da busca binária, em um array de 1.048.576 faz somente 23 comparações, eu não fazia idéia que a busca binária era tão eficiente assim, o mais interessante é que se dobrar o número de itens aumenta em apenas 1 a quantidade de comparações, ela parece não ser muito eficiente para array com poucos itens, mas para arrays gigantes faz uma diferença gigantesca.